# Database column datatype changed from bit to char(1) SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have an existing table with a column called `BlackWhite`, which is of `bit` type. It's either Black or White value (1 or 0 value). And now I have another Green data. So I need to change the column's datatype from `bit` to `char(1)`.

Can I ask couple of things here:

1. If the existing column datatype is changed from `bit` to `char(1)`, will it affect the other column foreign key constraints? I generated a script from Microsoft SQL server after changing the column type. I can see it drops the constraint first, then modify the type, and then create constraint again in the script. Or another option is to create a new column, populate the existing data to the new column, and delete the existing column?
2. After I change the datatype to `char(1)`, will the existing data (True or False) be automatically converted to either 1 or 0?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and in "SQL" one would use a `boolean` to store yes/no flags) Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend changing this differently.

Create a `Color` table:

```
+----+-------+
| Id | Name  |
+----+-------+
| 0  | Black |
+----+-------+
| 1  | White |
+----+-------+
| 2  | Green |
+----+-------+
```

Then do it in the following manner:

1. Add new nullable `ColorId` column
2. Fill `ColorId` with values from `BlackWhite`
3. Make `ColorId` non-nullable
4. Add FK constraint on `ColorId` to `Color` table
5. Make sure your application now uses only `ColorId`
6. Delete `BlackWhite` column eventually

This should be a seamless transition, you might need to change order of execution based on your requirements, but that should be really it.

Having this kind of table will allow to add new colors easy, will ensure data integrity and numeric field will take less space than char.

Comment: @Julia also - looking from types you gave us, I would guess you're using Microsoft's SQL Server. In my answer, I've given ids 0, 1 ad 2 for your colors, but in case you'd be using an ORM like EF Core - it doesn't play well with 0 ids, it treats those as new values. So it'd be better to start identity from 1. This might need a little bit more extra work but will prevent other headaches.

Comment: Exactly I am using Microsoft SQL server. That ID 0, 1, 2 is what I am thinking too. Perfect transition.

Comment: @Julia cool, just be careful with 0 ID. I'd suggest avoiding it as it can become troublesome.

Comment: Ok I am going to start from 1 thanks